# Google Cloud Storage pushing the files into bucket very slowly

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the below code to recursively get all the paths in the folder and push them one by one into the google cloud storage bucket. The problem is, it's extremely slow. I have around 30-40K files that need to be pushed every day and each one is taking like 0.25 to 0.5 second to push. Is there any way I could push them all together? In bulk? Or another way that makes it way faster?

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function getAllFilesInDirectoryRecursively(dir){
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir, {withFileTypes: true});
    for (const file of files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            yield* getAllFilesInDirectoryRecursively(path.join(dir, file.name));
        } else {
            yield path.join(dir, file.name);
        }
    }
}

const storage = new Storage();

(async function(){
    for (let filePath of getAllFilesInDirectoryRecursively('./main/')) {
        await storage.bucket('bucket.domain.com').upload('./' + filePath, {
            destination: filePath.replace('main', ''),
        });
    }
})()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `gcloud` CLI in case it is a one time job?  `gsutil cp -r ./main gs://bucket-name`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, that works, but this is part of a cronjob so we need to run it every day. We could do this via `exec()` but isn't it unreliable?

Comment: Where are you uploading files from (local machine, a VM, etc)? You can just schedule a cron job that runs the `gcloud` command every day.

Comment: @Dharmaraj It's for a VM, yes as I said, that's a solution I got, but it's unreliable. Pushing into the cloud should happen after a huge block of code that generates the files, and that 1) Using a cronjob outside the scope is not a good solution as we don't know when exactly the files creation finishes 2) Using it inside the cronjob through exec is not a good solution either since exec is not reliable.

Comment: You can still run the `gsutil` command after the files have generated by the code? If the script is in NodeJS, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63058273/13130697) should help.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I guess that's the only solution I got until Google creates a function that pushes them all together. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) to upload contents of a directory using:

```
gsutil cp -r ./main gs://bucket-name
```

To run this command periodically, you can use a cron job or [run the command from NodeJS script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63058273/13130697) after the files have been generated.

For a solution without `gsutil`, it might be better to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead of running all `upload` promises individually.